# Getting Routing-Information by Method Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, attributes

I use attribute Routing in my MVC-Project which works just fine:

```
[RoutePrefix("installation")]
public class InstController:Controller {
  [Route("inittest/{lang}")]
  public ActionResult InitTest(string lang) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Now I need to find a way to get the routing information just by the methodname. Eg:

```
string GetRoutingOf("MyNamespace.InstController.InitTest"); // returns "installation/inittest/{lang}"
```

Comment: Would be nice to leave a comment when downvoting so the question can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

```
private string GetRoute(string className, string methodName)
{
    var routes = RouteTable.Routes.ToList().OfType<Route>();
    foreach (var route in routes)
    {
        if (route.Defaults != null)
        {
            var controller = route.Defaults.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == "controller");
            var action = route.Defaults.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == "action");

            if (controller.Value != null && controller.Value.ToString() == className && action.Value != null && action.Value.ToString() == methodName)
            {
                return route.Url;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This has some limitations, though: If there are multiple Methods with the same name (eg. `void Select(int id)`, `void Select(string name)` this does not work.

classname and methodName would be "Inst" and "Inittest" in the example of my question and are retrieved through simple string-functions.